# Open date picker on span click

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

My Search Form is as follows.

```
<div class="search-bar-wrapper container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2"></div>
            <div class="col-md-8 search-bar">
                <span class="col-md-5 mag-name-field" contenteditable>
                </span>
                <span class="col-md-5 date-field datepicker fa fa-calendar open-datetimepicker" contenteditable>
                </span>
                <span class="col-md-2 btn-front">SEARCH</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2"></div>
        </div>
</div>
```

**I want to open a date picker on click of 'open-datetimepicker', either bootstrap date picker or jQuery datepicker.**

I tried several answers on SO. Nothing worked out. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Can you show the code that you have tried?

Comment: have you added any datepicker plugin yet. If yes let us know the name.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, using jquery:

```
<span class="col-md-5 date-field datepicker fa fa-calendar open-datetimepicker" contenteditable
     onclick="$('#yourDatepickerName').datepicker('show');">
</span>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using an input field. Make sure all the libraries are included and add the jQuery. Best of luck!

```
<link rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="search-bar-wrapper container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2"></div>
            <div class="col-md-8 search-bar">
                <span class="col-md-5 mag-name-field" contenteditable>
                </span>
                <input id="date" class="col-md-5 date-field datepicker fa fa-calendar open-datetimepicker" contenteditable/>
                <span class="col-md-2 btn-front">SEARCH</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2"></div>
        </div>
</div>
<script>
$( "#date" ).datepicker();
</script>
```

Comment: He was asked to make it in `span` tag